# .NET Reflector Add-in for renaming

Tags: .net, reflector, .net-reflector

Is there an existing .NET Reflector add-in that allows renaming of namespaces/classes/methods etc?

Comment: Are you trying to break open a binary file and arbitrarily rename the items inside?

Comment: Yes. Just renaming for ease of reading obfuscated code though, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Not for Reflector, but there is an add-in called ReSharper that plugs into VS itself, and has a lot of neat little refactoring tricks including "safe" renaming on many levels. you can find it at www.jetbrains.com.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) add-ins. It allow you to rename, edit, add, remove code, class, members, etc